# Are there high-availability options for On-premise applications using Azure

Tags: azure, azure-hybrid-connections

We have some dedicated LOB application on-premise applications. Access to these apps is through the public Internet. Active Directory Domain Services is used to authenticate users.

In Azure, there are multiple ways to create high-availability; is there something similar for on-premise apps using Azure? By this I mean if one on-premise system is down, traffic is routed to another app.

I know there are some options such as Application Gateway, Traffic manager and Front-door including Azure LB, my question is - are these the right services we should use in an on-premise setting?

Answer (score 0):

For your on premise environment, you can use Network Load balancing(NLB) feature of Windows Server. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/network-load-balancing), it has an Azure inspired feature too.